# Merge list into matrix

Tags: python-3.x, variables, matrix

I'm trying to merge 5 lists into one 2d matrix in Python. The lists are named a0 ... a4 (all of the same length)

```
while ( i <= len(a0) ):
    while ( k < 5):
        matrix[i][k] = #here I want to assign a0[i], a1[i],..., a5[i]
        k+=1
    i+=1
```

Is there a way to make this work or do I have to go with something like:

```
while ( i <= len(a0) ):
        matrix[i][0] = a0[i]
        matrix[i][1] = a1[i]
           ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a0 through a4 are already lists... you just need to put all of them into ONE BIG list.

Let me know if this works for you:

```
a0 = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
a1 = [str(x) for x in range(10, 20)]
a2 = [str(x) for x in range(20, 30)]
a3 = [str(x) for x in range(30, 40)]
a4 = [str(x) for x in range(40, 50)]

print("a0: {}".format(", ".join(a0)))
print("a1: {}".format(", ".join(a1)))
print("a2: {}".format(", ".join(a2)))
print("a3: {}".format(", ".join(a3)))
print("a4: {}".format(", ".join(a4)))

matrix = [
    a0,
    a1,
    a2,
    a3,
    a4
]

# Below is another way:
# matrix = []
# matrix.append(a0)
# matrix.append(a1)
# matrix.append(a2)
# matrix.append(a3)
# matrix.append(a4)

print("matrix[3][4]: {}".format(matrix[3][4]))
```

Output:

```
a0: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
a1: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
a2: 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
a3: 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39
a4: 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
matrix[3][4]: 34
```

Comment: Perfect this is so much better than loops!